# del a variable in python given a string containing the variable name

Tags: python

I hacked up some code to test my hypothesis of algo complexity for set intersection in python:

s3, s4, s5, s6, t3, t4, t5, t6 are all defined and are rather large - their intersections also happen to be quite large.

```
import timeit

s3, t3 = set(), set()
s4, t4 = set(), set()
s5, t5 = set(), set()
s6, t6 = set(), set()

for x in xrange(int(1e3)):
    s3.add(x)
    t3.add(x*2 + x)

for x in xrange(int(1e4)):
    s4.add(x)
    t4.add(x*2 + x)

for x in xrange(int(1e5)):
    s5.add(x)
    t5.add(x*2 + x)

for x in xrange(int(1e6)):
    s6.add(x)
    t6.add(x*2 + x)


def _test():
    for i in [3, 4, 5, 6]:
        for j in [3, 4, 5, 6]:
            if i >= j:
                s, t = 's' + str(i), 't' + str(j)
                print i, j
                print timeit.timeit('{0}.intersection({1})'.format(s, t), setup="from __main__ import {0}, {1}".format(s, t))
        eval('del s' + str(i))
```

But the following statement 'blows up'..

```
eval('del s' + str(i))
```

Any ideas?

I would also be interested in any ideas to make my hacky code less hacky.

Thanks

Comment: what is "blows up"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should be aware that the slow execution time you are seeing is due to `timeit`. The algorithm itself is super fast.

Secondly you can create list of sets:

```
s = [set(), set(), ...]
```

and then delete the element from that list

```
del s[i]
```

in your case:

```
import timeit

s = [set(), set(), set(), set()]
t = [set(), set(), set(), set()]

for x in xrange(int(1e3)):
    s[0].add(x)
    t[0].add(x*2 + x)

for x in xrange(int(1e4)):
    s[1].add(x)
    t[1].add(x*2 + x)

for x in xrange(int(1e5)):
    s[2].add(x)
    t[2].add(x*2 + x)

for x in xrange(int(1e6)):
    s[3].add(x)
    t[3].add(x*2 + x)


def _test():
    for i, _ in enumerate(s):
        for j, _ in enumerate(t):
            if i >= j:
                print i, j
                print timeit.timeit('s[{0}].intersection(t[{1}])'.format(i, j), setup="from __main__ import s, t")
        del s[i]
```

Thirdly for larger datasets you can probably speed up the process using NumPy:

```
import timeit
import numpy
import itertools

s = [numpy.arange(l) for l in [1e3, 1e4, 1e5, 1e6]]
t = [ss * 3 for ss in s]  # x*2 + x == x*3

for (i, ss), (j, tt) in itertools.product(enumerate(s), enumerate(t)):
    if i >= j:
        print i, j
        numpy.intersect1d(ss, tt, assume_unique=True)
```

Comment: Yep, that makes everything better.
Thanks

Comment: You can also create another list for xrange sizes, so there aren't four for loops anymore.

Comment: and you could use 'for i in range(len(s))' instead of enumerate. Thanks alot :).

Comment: I have added another example using NumPy, if performance is a concern.